# AWS Kinesis Firehose Lambda Data Transformation with encryption in node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kms

I am trying to write a data transformation for an Aurora Postgres data stream. The identity transformation gives me objects like this:

```
{
    "type": "DatabaseActivityMonitoringRecords",
    "version": "1.0",
    "databaseActivityEvents": "AYADeLZrKReAa/7tgBmd/d06ybQAXwA...BABVoaWV1Fi8LyA==",
    "key": "AADDDVAS ...pztPgaw=="
}
```

So it appears to me that I need to decrypt these. I have the `arn` of the key attached to the database in question but I cannot get the data transformation to work. Here is what I have so far:

console.log('Loading function');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    /* Process the list of records and transform them */

    const output = event.records.map((record) => {

        const keyId = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:501..89:key/1...d7"; // I don't need this?
        const CiphertextBlob = record.data;
        const kmsClient = new AWS.KMS({region: 'us-east-1'});
        const pt = kmsClient.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob }, (err, data) => {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else {
            const { Plaintext } = data;
            console.log(data);
            return Plaintext;
          }
        });
        return { old_data : record.data,};
    });
    console.log(`Processing completed.  Successful records ${output.length}.`);
    return { records: output };
};
```

This gives me the baffling error `"errorMessage": "Error: Unable to stringify response body"` I am following the example outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/programming-encryption.html#decryption

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?